# Creating a dynamic javascript bundle with wro4j

Tags: javascript, bundling-and-minification, wro4j

Am trying to create this infrastructure using wro4j, with which a user can decide which js files to bundle by just editing the template and not touching any java code.
So, some request like http ://.../bundle/scrip1.js/scrip2.js/script3.js/script4.js
would return a bundle that has all four scripts in the order asked for.

But, having to specify the group with resources beforehand in xml or in a custom WroModelFactory implementation still does not give enough freedom to create bundles based on requests.

Any ideas on how to go about this ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this seems to be, to wrap the WroFilter in a custom filter, intercept the call for bundling and store the bundle information in a location that the WroModelFactory can pick up and create the model accordingly.